# How can I overwrite a method which is located in the vendor directory?

Tags: php, laravel, overwrite

As you know, all folder/files that are located in the vendor directory will be renew when you run `composer install`. So modifying codes in there is a wrong practice.

Also, I need to modify `DatabaseChannel` class which exists under `Illuminate\Notifications\Channels` namespace *(and located in the `vendor` directory)*. It has a method named `send` that I need to modify.

Any idea how can I do that? in which class should I define `send` method again and overwrite the my codes? Should I make a new class with the same as `DatabaseChannel`? Where should I place it? Should be that class extended from the one which is in the vendor directory? How can I say the compiler to use the function I defined not the one which is defined inside the vendor directory?

Comment: make a method with same name in child class and it will be overridden

Comment: Don't do this. You should only ever overwrite methods, and extend classes, you own. The reason for this is that the underlying code might change and break yours. For instance, an underlying method gets an extra argument, which your method doesn't have, and that will generate an strict standards warings. Or you've defined a method in your class that the maker of the underlying class also decided to use, and they clash.

Comment: you mean _overwrite_ or _override_?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know for sure if you can. But you definitely shouldn't.
Not only you depend on the code in the vendor folder. Potentially dozens of other dependencies do too.

If you really want, you should create a fork from the package you are trying to change. Make the change, and add the repository to your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
     {
         "type": "git",
         "url": "https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php"
     }
],
```

Then you can install the dependency just like you would do normally.

Answer (score 0):

you should never overwrite vendor files, and it's useless anyway.

I suggest you make a new channel and make it extend DatabaseChannel, then you can overwrite that method and use the new channel instead of the old one. [refer to laravel docs to make a new channel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#custom-channels)

this way, your class will be up to date with the package, and no mess is required